# Subscribe to an event emitter that has 2 parameters?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, reactxp, react-native-ble-plx

My context is React Native / RxJS / TypeScript

I'm trying to subscribe to an event emitter that has 2 parameters.

The function prototype is like this:

```
handleUpdateValueForDiskStorage = (error: BleError | null, characteristic: Characteristic | null) => {
```

...
     }

When I try to subscribe like the following, the code won't compile:

```
this.emitter = fromEventPattern(this.addHandler, this.removeHandler);
this.rxSubscription = this.emitter.subscribe(this.handleUpdateValueForDiskStorage);
```

The error is:
Argument of type '(error: BleError | null, characteristic: Characteristic | null) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any) => void'.

However it seems that I can only have one argument coming from the event.

I've done some research and found [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2431#issuecomment-283364650). This is about projecting the 2 arguments into an array.

I don't know if this is still valid and can't seem to wrap my head around it to do the same.

Comment: have you tried solution you linked with project function? e.g. `fromEventPattern(this.addHandler, this.removeHandler, (err, char)=>[err, char])`

Comment: Now yes, thanks for your help.